# Participating x participative

Tags: grammar, differences, adjectives

Is it possible to say that a person is 'participating'?

E.g.: John is a participating student.

Instead of:

John is a participative student.

Comment: What do you find in dictionaries? This question is off-topic for this site because it doesn't show any effort put into research.

Comment: I'd like to state that, as a user and learner of the language I have looked up the entry in a dictionary matter-of-factly, however unsatisfied with what I have found, I decide to bring the question into discussion here. Regards.

Comment: You haven't attracted any close votes, so you're apparently doing fine without including, for example (of the things that might help people provide more useful answers for you), the *reason* you're unsatisfied with what you found in the dictionary and *what*, exactly, it was you found in *which* dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Participating is the present participle of participate, basically a present tense verb. "John is a participating student" can only be used when you mean that John is a student that is *currently* participating in something. "John is a participative student" means John is a student that likes to participate in things.

Comment: Thank you! That clarifies my doubt. So there's no scenario in which "participating" works as an adjective. 
Regards.

Comment: If one of the answers here answers your question you should accept that answer so that it is "closed" and others can be sure about what the answer is.

Answer (score 1):

*Participating*, the present participle of the verb *to participate*, is used for people who are engaged in some activity:

> The Sheriff is **participating** in this Monday's forum on traffic safety.

*Participative* is most often used to describe an activity in which others participate.  The first use I can find is a religious one, in [*Discourses on various subjects*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UeZLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA27&dq=%22participative%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifqLXp-KzLAhUGKiYKHXALA-I4RhDoAQhBMAY#v=onepage&q=%22participative%22&f=false) (1807) by Jeremy Taylor:

> ... for God's nature is indivisible and incommunicable; but it is
>   spoken ***participative*** ... that is of this new and God-like nature
>   given to every person that serves God, whereby he is sanctified and
>   made the child of God ....

That is, although God is a unity unto himself and not understandable by humans, yet we can take part in his nature by serving (i.e., believing in) him.  From the divine we arrive in more recent time to the word's incorporation into business babble. From [*Financial Management, policies and practices*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-QZIAQAAIAAJ&q=%22participative%22&dq=%22participative%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKvaiuya3LAhUDLyYKHWW-DLwQ6AEIJzAD) (1963) by H A Ward

> The short-run trend definitely indicates a growth of decentralization
>   or **participative** thought and action by managements at various
>   levels of the pyramid.

describing a corporate management style in which those in the lower levels of a company take part in the policy decisions usually reserved for the higher levels.  There are **participative** budgeting, conferences, decisions, design, leadership, management, methods, programs, teaching, theory, thought, etc.

*Participative* is applied to individuals far less often than *participating*.  For example, the google finds about 2.6K references to *participative student* (whose opposite is the *avoidant*) and about 113K for *participating student*.  (And the former includes many false drops like *participative student-led activities*).